# is it possible to change the ISE Access endpoint from internal to external

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to change the ISE Access endpoint from internal to external  once the ISE is provisioned or configured.

Comment: You need to provide more messages about what you want.

Comment: After creating the ISE for logic app as internal access endpoint in Azure, is it possible to change it to External rather re-creating it.